# Sending data over the air and after completion end the operation using RxAndroidBLE

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-android, rxandroidble

I am trying to send the `128` bytes of the block to BLE Controller using the `RxAndroidBle` library. the flow to send data from mobile to BLE controller is as follows

1. Connect with BLE Controller
2. Start OTA (sending 1)
3. Send CRC  (of the data block)
4. Send data block
5. wait for 2 seconds
6. repeat step 3
7. END OTA (sending 2)

Here is snapshot of a code

```
.flatMap(rxBleConnection -> prepareWriting())
.flatMapIterable(otaMetaData -> otaMetaData)
.zipWith(Observable.interval(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS), (item, interval) -> item)
.doOnNext(metaData -> {
    otaMetaData = metaData;
})
.map(otaMetaData -> {
    return mRxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(OTA_CHECKSUM, otaMetaData.getCrcBlock()).toObservable();
})

.doOnNext(otaMetaData -> {
    Log.e(TAG, "Writing CRC " + Arrays.toString(BLEUtils.toHex(otaMetaData.getCrcBlock())));


})
.map(bytes -> {
    return mRxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(OTA_DATA, otaMetaData.getDataBlock()).toObservable();
})
.doOnNext(otaMetaData -> {
    Log.e(TAG, "Writing Data " + Arrays.toString(BLEUtils.toHex(otaMetaData.getDataBlock())));

})
.flatMap(bytes -> mRxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(OTA_CONTROL,OTA_DATA_END).toObservable())
```

The problem is while sending the `END OTA` because as the `flatMapIterable` returns 20 items, `.flatMap(bytes -> mRxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(OTA_CONTROL,OTA_DATA_END)` is getting called 20 times.

So, I am not sure how I can send the `OTA_DATA_END` command when all the 20 items get processed. Moreover, any suggestion to improve the existing code is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `flatMapIterable()` with `toList()`. Try to add `toList()` operator before `OTA_DATA_END` command like:

```
.toList() // wait for all commands to complete
.flatMap(bytes -> mRxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(OTA_CONTROL,OTA_DATA_END).toObservable())
```

**EDIT**

Better to separate steps like

```
.flatMap(rxBleConnection -> prepareWriting())
.flatMap(otaMetaData -> Observable.fromIterable(otaMetaData)
        .zipWith(Observable.interval(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS), (metaData, interval) -> metaData)
        .flatMap(metaData -> {
            return mRxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(OTA_CHECKSUM, metaData.getCrcBlock())
                    .toObservable();
        }, (metaData, bytes) -> metaData) /* result selector */
        .flatMap(metaData -> {
            return mRxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(OTA_DATA, metaData.getDataBlock())
                    .toObservable();
        }, (metaData, bytes) -> metaData)
        .toList()
        .toObservable()
)
.flatMap(otaMetaData -> {
    return mRxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(OTA_CONTROL, OTA_DATA_END)
            .toObservable();
})
```

Comment: Two things, after adding `toList()` I had to use `map` instead of the `flatMap` as `toList` is returning `Single<List<Observale<byte[]>>>`  and secondly after using `map` control is got going there hence  `.map(observables -> mRxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(OTADictionary.OTA_CONTROL, OTADictionary.OTA_DATA_END).toObservable())`  not getting fired

Comment: One question, if `mRxBleConnection.writeCharacteristic(...)` method returns `Observable/Single`, how you use `.map(otaMetaData -> )` and `.map(bytes -> )`? I think here should be `flatMap/flatMapSingle` instead of `map`. Yes, `toList()` returns `Single`, if you want `Observable` use `toObservable()` after `toList()` for conversion back to `Observable`. Also see edited answer.